# sign .apk files ..getting jarsigner error:

Tags: android, apk, jarsigner

I downloaded MyFiles.apk from internet and trying to do sign MyFiles.apk using jarsigner tool.
I followed every step

but getting

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException:keystore load: D:\path_to_keystore\mykeystore.keystore(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

what is this? how to solve?

You can see this link of screenshot of my error

[image]

Comment: what is the path_to_keystore in D:\path_to_keystore\mykeystore.keystore ?

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshot you posted, you're telling jarsigner that your keystore is located at `D:\path_to_keystore\mykeystore.keystore`. This is highly unlikely, and it seems you've copied the command straight from the documentation. Try providing the actual path to your keystore, where the file is located on your system

If you haven't got a keystore yet, you'll have to generate one as shown in [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) part of the documentation.

Comment: Addition: if you don't have a keystore, create one first. And a key in it. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev This is the OP's second question on this today. Already linked him to that document earlier in my answer.

Comment: Badly phrased, sorry. What I mean, if the OP does not realize that he/she needs to substitute a placeholder path for a real one, most likely he/she does not have a keystore at all.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I see your point. Edited my answer to link OP to the part of the documentation that discusses making a private key